# Where can I find the function that formats a log string and its parameters with the new Structured Logging format?

Tags: c#, logging, format, ilogger, structured-logging

Where can I find the function that formats a log string and its parameters with the new Structured Logging format. I'm looking for the equivalent of "string.Format(..." but for Structured Logging.

I didn't find the information in the doc: [How to use structured logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#formatting-of-the-message)

I receive the proper formatter function (the one I'm looking for) if I define my own Logger so it should exists somewhere? Where and how to use it?

For example:

```
string relatedBug = "toto";
return FuncICannotFindToFormatLog("Log a bug related to {relatedBug}", relatedBug);  
result ==> "Log a bug related to toto"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it and it appears to be Microsoft Internal. This is the code (slightly adapted to run with my code).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace General.LogEx
{
    // Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
    // The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.

    /// <summary>
    /// Formatter to convert the named format items like {NamedformatItem} to <see cref="string.Format(IFormatProvider, string, object)"/> format.
    /// </summary>
    internal sealed class LogValuesFormatter
    {
        private const string NullValue = "(null)";
        private static readonly char[] FormatDelimiters = { ',', ':' };
        private readonly string _format;
        private readonly List<string> _valueNames = new List<string>();

        // NOTE: If this assembly ever builds for netcoreapp, the below code should change to:
        // - Be annotated as [SkipLocalsInit] to avoid zero'ing the stackalloc'd char span
        // - Format _valueNames.Count directly into a span

        public LogValuesFormatter(string format)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(format);

            OriginalFormat = format;

            var vsb = new ValueStringBuilder(stackalloc char[256]);
            int scanIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = format.Length;

            while (scanIndex < endIndex)
            {
                int openBraceIndex = FindBraceIndex(format, '{', scanIndex, endIndex);
                if (scanIndex == 0 && openBraceIndex == endIndex)
                {
                    // No holes found.
                    _format = format;
                    return;
                }

                int closeBraceIndex = FindBraceIndex(format, '}', openBraceIndex, endIndex);

                if (closeBraceIndex == endIndex)
                {
                    vsb.Append(format.AsSpan(scanIndex, endIndex - scanIndex));
                    scanIndex = endIndex;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Format item syntax : { index[,alignment][ :formatString] }.
                    int formatDelimiterIndex = FindIndexOfAny(format, FormatDelimiters, openBraceIndex, closeBraceIndex);

                    vsb.Append(format.AsSpan(scanIndex, openBraceIndex - scanIndex + 1));
                    vsb.Append(_valueNames.Count.ToString());
                    _valueNames.Add(format.Substring(openBraceIndex + 1, formatDelimiterIndex - openBraceIndex - 1));
                    vsb.Append(format.AsSpan(formatDelimiterIndex, closeBraceIndex - formatDelimiterIndex + 1));

                    scanIndex = closeBraceIndex + 1;
                }
            }

            _format = vsb.ToString();
        }

        public string OriginalFormat { get; private set; }
        public List<string> ValueNames => _valueNames;

        private static int FindBraceIndex(string format, char brace, int startIndex, int endIndex)
        {
            // Example: {{prefix{{{Argument}}}suffix}}.
            int braceIndex = endIndex;
            int scanIndex = startIndex;
            int braceOccurrenceCount = 0;

            while (scanIndex < endIndex)
            {
                if (braceOccurrenceCount > 0 && format[scanIndex] != brace)
                {
                    if (braceOccurrenceCount % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        // Even number of '{' or '}' found. Proceed search with next occurrence of '{' or '}'.
                        braceOccurrenceCount = 0;
                        braceIndex = endIndex;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // An unescaped '{' or '}' found.
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (format[scanIndex] == brace)
                {
                    if (brace == '}')
                    {
                        if (braceOccurrenceCount == 0)
                        {
                            // For '}' pick the first occurrence.
                            braceIndex = scanIndex;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // For '{' pick the last occurrence.
                        braceIndex = scanIndex;
                    }

                    braceOccurrenceCount++;
                }

                scanIndex++;
            }

            return braceIndex;
        }

        private static int FindIndexOfAny(string format, char[] chars, int startIndex, int endIndex)
        {
            int findIndex = format.IndexOfAny(chars, startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
            return findIndex == -1 ? endIndex : findIndex;
        }

        public string Format(object?[]? values)
        {
            object?[]? formattedValues = values;

            if (values != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    object formattedValue = FormatArgument(values[i]);
                    // If the formatted value is changed, we allocate and copy items to a new array to avoid mutating the array passed in to this method
                    if (!ReferenceEquals(formattedValue, values[i]))
                    {
                        formattedValues = new object[values.Length];
                        Array.Copy(values, formattedValues, i);
                        formattedValues[i++] = formattedValue;
                        for (; i < values.Length; i++)
                        {
                            formattedValues[i] = FormatArgument(values[i]);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _format, formattedValues ?? Array.Empty<object>());
        }

        // NOTE: This method mutates the items in the array if needed to avoid extra allocations, and should only be used when caller expects this to happen
        internal string FormatWithOverwrite(object?[]? values)
        {
            if (values != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = FormatArgument(values[i]);
                }
            }

            return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _format, values ?? Array.Empty<object>());
        }

        internal string Format()
        {
            return _format;
        }

        internal string Format(object? arg0)
        {
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _format, FormatArgument(arg0));
        }

        internal string Format(object? arg0, object? arg1)
        {
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _format, FormatArgument(arg0), FormatArgument(arg1));
        }

        internal string Format(object? arg0, object? arg1, object? arg2)
        {
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _format, FormatArgument(arg0), FormatArgument(arg1), FormatArgument(arg2));
        }

        public KeyValuePair<string, object?> GetValue(object?[] values, int index)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index > _valueNames.Count)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
            }

            if (_valueNames.Count > index)
            {
                return new KeyValuePair<string, object?>(_valueNames[index], values[index]);
            }

            return new KeyValuePair<string, object?>("{OriginalFormat}", OriginalFormat);
        }

        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object?>> GetValues(object[] values)
        {
            var valueArray = new KeyValuePair<string, object?>[values.Length + 1];
            for (int index = 0; index != _valueNames.Count; ++index)
            {
                valueArray[index] = new KeyValuePair<string, object?>(_valueNames[index], values[index]);
            }

            valueArray[valueArray.Length - 1] = new KeyValuePair<string, object?>("{OriginalFormat}", OriginalFormat);
            return valueArray;
        }

        private object FormatArgument(object? value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return NullValue;
            }

            // since 'string' implements IEnumerable, special case it
            if (value is string)
            {
                return value;
            }

            // if the value implements IEnumerable, build a comma separated string.
            if (value is IEnumerable enumerable)
            {
                var vsb = new ValueStringBuilder(stackalloc char[256]);
                bool first = true;
                foreach (object? e in enumerable)
                {
                    if (!first)
                    {
                        vsb.Append(", ");
                    }

                    vsb.Append(e != null ? e.ToString() : NullValue);
                    first = false;
                }
                return vsb.ToString();
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
}


using System.Buffers;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace System.Text;

internal ref struct ValueStringBuilder
{
    private char[] _arrayToReturnToPool;

    private Span<char> _chars;

    private int _pos;

    public int Length
    {
        get
        {
            return _pos;
        }
        set
        {
            _pos = value;
        }
    }

    public int Capacity => _chars.Length;

    public ref char this[int index] => ref _chars[index];

    public Span<char> RawChars => _chars;

    public ValueStringBuilder(Span<char> initialBuffer)
    {
        _arrayToReturnToPool = null;
        _chars = initialBuffer;
        _pos = 0;
    }

    public ValueStringBuilder(int initialCapacity)
    {
        _arrayToReturnToPool = ArrayPool<char>.Shared.Rent(initialCapacity);
        _chars = _arrayToReturnToPool;
        _pos = 0;
    }

    public void EnsureCapacity(int capacity)
    {
        if ((uint)capacity > (uint)_chars.Length)
        {
            Grow(capacity - _pos);
        }
    }

    public ref char GetPinnableReference()
    {
        return ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(_chars);
    }

    public ref char GetPinnableReference(bool terminate)
    {
        if (terminate)
        {
            EnsureCapacity(Length + 1);
            _chars[Length] = '\0';
        }

        return ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(_chars);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string result = _chars.Slice(0, _pos).ToString();
        Dispose();
        return result;
    }

    public ReadOnlySpan<char> AsSpan(bool terminate)
    {
        if (terminate)
        {
            EnsureCapacity(Length + 1);
            _chars[Length] = '\0';
        }

        return _chars.Slice(0, _pos);
    }

    public ReadOnlySpan<char> AsSpan()
    {
        return _chars.Slice(0, _pos);
    }

    public ReadOnlySpan<char> AsSpan(int start)
    {
        return _chars.Slice(start, _pos - start);
    }

    public ReadOnlySpan<char> AsSpan(int start, int length)
    {
        return _chars.Slice(start, length);
    }

    public bool TryCopyTo(Span<char> destination, out int charsWritten)
    {
        if (_chars.Slice(0, _pos).TryCopyTo(destination))
        {
            charsWritten = _pos;
            Dispose();
            return true;
        }

        charsWritten = 0;
        Dispose();
        return false;
    }

    public void Insert(int index, char value, int count)
    {
        if (_pos > _chars.Length - count)
        {
            Grow(count);
        }

        int length = _pos - index;
        _chars.Slice(index, length).CopyTo(_chars.Slice(index + count));
        _chars.Slice(index, count).Fill(value);
        _pos += count;
    }

    public void Insert(int index, string? s)
    {
        if (s != null)
        {
            int length = s.Length;
            if (_pos > _chars.Length - length)
            {
                Grow(length);
            }

            int length2 = _pos - index;
            _chars.Slice(index, length2).CopyTo(_chars.Slice(index + length));
            s.CopyTo(_chars.Slice(index));
            _pos += length;
        }
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public void Append(char c)
    {
        int pos = _pos;
        if ((uint)pos < (uint)_chars.Length)
        {
            _chars[pos] = c;
            _pos = pos + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            GrowAndAppend(c);
        }
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public void Append(string? s)
    {
        if (s != null)
        {
            int pos = _pos;
            if (s.Length == 1 && (uint)pos < (uint)_chars.Length)
            {
                _chars[pos] = s[0];
                _pos = pos + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                AppendSlow(s);
            }
        }
    }

    private void AppendSlow(string s)
    {
        int pos = _pos;
        if (pos > _chars.Length - s.Length)
        {
            Grow(s.Length);
        }

        s.CopyTo(_chars.Slice(pos));
        _pos += s.Length;
    }

    public void Append(char c, int count)
    {
        if (_pos > _chars.Length - count)
        {
            Grow(count);
        }

        Span<char> span = _chars.Slice(_pos, count);
        for (int i = 0; i < span.Length; i++)
        {
            span[i] = c;
        }

        _pos += count;
    }

    //public unsafe void Append(char* value, int length)
    //{
    //    int pos = _pos;
    //    if (pos > _chars.Length - length)
    //    {
    //        Grow(length);
    //    }

    //    Span<char> span = _chars.Slice(_pos, length);
    //    for (int i = 0; i < span.Length; i++)
    //    {
    //        span[i] = *(value++);
    //    }

    //    _pos += length;
    //}

    public void Append(ReadOnlySpan<char> value)
    {
        int pos = _pos;
        if (pos > _chars.Length - value.Length)
        {
            Grow(value.Length);
        }

        value.CopyTo(_chars.Slice(_pos));
        _pos += value.Length;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public Span<char> AppendSpan(int length)
    {
        int pos = _pos;
        if (pos > _chars.Length - length)
        {
            Grow(length);
        }

        _pos = pos + length;
        return _chars.Slice(pos, length);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void GrowAndAppend(char c)
    {
        Grow(1);
        Append(c);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void Grow(int additionalCapacityBeyondPos)
    {
        int minimumLength = (int)Math.Max((uint)(_pos + additionalCapacityBeyondPos), Math.Min((uint)(_chars.Length * 2), 2147483591u));
        char[] array = ArrayPool<char>.Shared.Rent(minimumLength);
        _chars.Slice(0, _pos).CopyTo(array);
        char[] arrayToReturnToPool = _arrayToReturnToPool;
        _chars = (_arrayToReturnToPool = array);
        if (arrayToReturnToPool != null)
        {
            ArrayPool<char>.Shared.Return(arrayToReturnToPool);
        }
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public void Dispose()
    {
        char[] arrayToReturnToPool = _arrayToReturnToPool;
        this = default(ValueStringBuilder);
        if (arrayToReturnToPool != null)
        {
            ArrayPool<char>.Shared.Return(arrayToReturnToPool);
        }
    }
}
```